# Python - Loop through URLs, finding text, writing to new list

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

im trying to go through a list of urls to find something in the html text and writing it to a new list. The issue I have is that although I have a for Loop it outputs only the last url (there are 500 in the list "urls"). I do not know how to make it iterate write and then go to the next iteration instead of iterating and then just writing the last one in the list. Any ideas on how to make that work?

```
for url in urls:
    try:
         page = urlopen(url)
    except:
        print("Error opening the URL")    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find('div', {"class": "sp-m-box-section"})
    article = []
        
    for url in urls:
        article = article.append(content)   #here I am completely unsure how to handle it
print(article)
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
article = []

for url in urls:
    try:
         page = urlopen(url)
    except:
        print("Error opening the URL")    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find('div', {"class": "sp-m-box-section"})       
    article.append(content)

print(article)
```

Comment: remove your assignment `article = article.append(content)` to `article.append(content)` @kdr

Comment: It did solve the issue at hand. Thanks! 
Now I will be building this with an if condition. If find text, append x and if not find text append y. Let's see :D

Answer (score 0):

Few issues here.

1. you overwrite your `article` list after each iteration by declaring `article=[]`. So it will always have an empty list even when you append. After the last iteration, it doesn't create the `article=[]`, leaving you with the last thing it appended.
2. Why iterate through the urls twice?
3. I changed it to handle the `try/except` differently.

Basically, try to read the page. If it doesn't the error is raised and continues to then next url (there's no sense in processing the html if it can't read it...plus you'd get an error there as well)

Give this a try:

```
article = []
for url in urls:
    try:
         page = urlopen(url)
    except:
        print("Error opening the URL") 
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find('div', {"class": "sp-m-box-section"})
    article.append(content.text) # <- here I'm assuming you want the actual text/content, not the html  

print(article)
```

Comment: Thanks! 
For this I am getting: 
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'"
I tried it with: 
soup.body.findAll(text='Example')
But it gives the same error.

Comment: I had a typo. Try it agin with the edit I made above

Comment: This is what I get: 

---> 25     article.append(content.text) # <- here I'm assuming you want the actual text/content, not the html



AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'